# In ISO 8601 does 'P1D' mean midnight tonight? 24 hours from now? Midnight tomorrow night?

Tags: iso8601

I have a virtual assistant app that includes a task manager. Some 'daily' tasks (like 'Check the mail' need to drop off at midnight so they don't clutter up the task list.

We use ISO 8601 to control how long until the task falls off the list.

I've looked all over trying to get clarity on the definition of a "D" day.
For example: Does P1D mean 24 hours? Midnight tomorrow? Midnight tonight?

I'm trying to achieve midnight tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [interval](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals), not a specific time of the day and thus it is meaningless without a starting point.

So in this context, this probably means that the task is dropped after 24 hours it had finished.